# how the function rand in <stdlib.h> library work?

Tags: c

```
for ( i=1; i<= 20; i++)
    printf("10%d" , 1 + ( rand() % 6 ) );
```

Can anyone explain how was the code running?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: just read it from the man pages: man 3 rand (or search the web for that manpage)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: Certinaly code should be `"10%d"` --> `"%10d"`.

Comment: i got confused with this part: 1 + (rand()%6)

Comment: why can't be like this 1 + (rand()%5,4,3,2)?

Comment: `rand()%6` will give a number between 0 and 5 inclusive. Adding 1 to this will give a number between 1 and 6 inclusive

Comment: You could write `1 + (rand()%5, 4, 3, 2)`, but the answer will always be 3 because the comma operator evaluates its left operand and throws the result away, and then evaluates the right operand and yields that as the result.  And in this case, that means it evaluates `rand()%5` (at least in principle), then 4, 3 and finally 2, so the end result is `1 + 2` or `3`, with `rand()` having been called.  Many compilers will warn you that the 4 and 3 terms are pointless as they have no side effects.  The call to `rand()` has side-effects; the `%5` does not.

Comment: i noticed that the same sequence of value was printed every time i compiled. How can i make the sequence of value be random number?

Comment: @chrisjan you need to **seed** it using `srand` as in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()` is a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Given a “seed value”, specified by `srand()`, sequential calls to `rand()` will produce a sequence of numbers which approximate a sequence of truly random values. A common way to produce a program which generates different pseudorandom values on every run is to seed the random number generator with the current time—`srand(time(NULL))`. A simple kind of pseudorandom number generator is a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register), and a commonly used one is the [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).